# Calling an extension method that uses expressions and delegates in its parameter in C#

Tags: c#, lambda, delegates, extension-methods, .net-4.5

Consider the below statement:

```
recorder.AddActivity(new Activity { ActivityName = "DeepSeaDiving", DayOfWeek = DayOfWeek.Monday });
```

Instead of this, there was a post [here](http://suryagaddipati.wordpress.com/2009/03/14/code-as-data-in-c-taking-advantage-of-expression-trees/), using `Expression Trees` for fancy-calling like this:

```
WeeklyActivityRecorder weeklyActivities = new WeeklyActivityRecorder () .WithActivities( Monday => "Lawn Moving",Tuesday => "Cooking");
```

I saw that extension method [here](http://suryagaddipati.wordpress.com/2009/03/14/code-as-data-in-c-taking-advantage-of-expression-trees/),  and which is given below.

```
public static WeeklyActivityRecorder WithActivities(this WeeklyActivityRecorder recorder, params Expression<Func<DayOfWeek, string>>[] activityList) 
    {
    foreach (var activity in activityList)
                {
                    LambdaExpression expression = activity;
                    ConstantExpression enteredActivity = expression.Body as ConstantExpression;
                    DayOfWeek day = expression.Parameters[0];
                    recorder.AddActivity(new Activity{DayOfWeek = day, ActivityName = activity});
                }

                return recorder;
    }
```

But, when I compile this, the compiler is unhappy about the extension method and complains that `Cannot convert sourceType **ParameterExpression** to **DayOfWeek**.

Any ideas what I am missing here ?

Comment: You can't use the same parameter name as local variables do. By `day` within lambda you declare parameter name and it should be different.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Invoking an Extension method with an Expression as one of its parameter in C#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19490247/invoking-an-extension-method-with-an-expression-as-one-of-its-parameter-in-c-sha)

Answer (score 3):

You need to pass a valid lambda.. you're passing in an actual `DayOfWeek`:

```
recorder.WithActivities(lambda_variable_here => "LawnMoving");
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But, whats `lambda_variable_here' mean ?

Comment: I'm going to suggest you read up on lambdas before continuing. They are a bigger topic than the format of SO allows.

Comment: @nowhewhomustnotbenamed. I suggest you to read [Lambda Expressions (C# Programming Guide)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb397687.aspx) to understand what is lambda variable and lambda expressions

Comment: @SimonWhitehead: Ok. Will do. thanks for the links . I ll post a new question explaining in an exact way. Thanks.

Comment: You should make a new question. This is now different and none of the answers cover it.

Answer (score 1):

You need to pass parameter, but you try to create lambda, where parameter name is static property, which is roughly equivalent to:

```
public string SomeMethodName(DayOfWeek.Monday) //incorrect method declaration
{

}
```

You need to call `WithActivities` method like

```
recorder.WithActivities(dayOfWeek => "LawnMoving"); //dayOfWeek is a parameter name
```

If you need to pass conversion method from `DayOfWeek` to `String`, you can use Dictionary, like this:

```
var recorder = new WeeklyActivityRecorder();

var daysTranslation = new Dictionary<DayOfWeek, string>()
{
    {DayOfWeek.Monday, "LawnMoving"}
    //other pairs
};

recorder.WithActivities(dayOfWeek => daysTranslation[dayOfWeek]);
```

Comment: thanks for the Good explanation (in the first block). But, please see my edit. `dayOfWeek` also does not work.

Comment: @Ilaya Ivanov: I tried, as given in the second block, Declared a local variable called `dayOfWeek` and then passed it inside. But, compiler is not happy.

Comment: @nowhewhomustnotbenamed. you need to use different names for local variable and lambda parameter name. Add your desired goals to the question.

Comment: Edited the post explaining full scenario