# Invoking an Extension method with an Expression as one of its parameter in C#

Tags: c#, delegates, extension-methods, .net-4.5, expression-trees

Consider the below statement:

```
recorder.AddActivity(new Activity { ActivityName = "DeepSeaDiving", DayOfWeek = DayOfWeek.Monday });
```

Instead of this, there was a post [here](http://suryagaddipati.wordpress.com/2009/03/14/code-as-data-in-c-taking-advantage-of-expression-trees/), using `Expression Trees` for fancy-calling like this:

```
 new WeeklyActivityRecorder () .WithActivities( Monday => "Lawn Moving",Tuesday => "Cooking");
```

I saw that extension method [here](http://suryagaddipati.wordpress.com/2009/03/14/code-as-data-in-c-taking-advantage-of-expression-trees/),  and which is given below.

```
public static WeeklyActivityRecorder WithActivities(this WeeklyActivityRecorder recorder, params Expression<Func<DayOfWeek, string>>[] activityList) 
    {
    foreach (var activity in activityList)
                {
                    LambdaExpression expression = activity;
                    ConstantExpression enteredActivity = expression.Body as ConstantExpression;
                    DayOfWeek day = expression.Parameters[0];
                    recorder.AddActivity(new Activity{DayOfWeek = day, ActivityName = activity});
                }

                return recorder;
    }
```

But, when I compile this, the compiler is unhappy about the extension method and complains that `Cannot convert sourceType **ParameterExpression** to **DayOfWeek**.

And the related code for the classes used above are as below:

```
public class Activity
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Gets the activity name.
    /// </summary>
    public string ActivityName { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets The day of week.
    /// </summary>
    public DayOfWeek DayOfWeek { get; set; }
}

public class WeeklyActivityRecorder
{
    private List<Activity> Activities { get; set; }

    public WeeklyActivityRecorder()
    {

    }

    public List<Activity> GetAllActivities()
    {
        return this.Activities;
    }

    public void AddActivity(Activity activity)
    {
        if (this.Activities == null)
        {
            this.Activities = new List<Activity>();
        }

        if (activity != null)
        {
            this.Activities.Add(activity);
        }
    }
}
```

Any ideas what I am missing here ?

Comment: First of all, you should realize that `Monday => "Lawn Moving"` is an abuse of the language. The name of a parameter shouldn't be important and it's also not checked at compile time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not 100% sure what that article was driving at.. but I have a feeling you're doing it all wrong.

You can however, get it to work as I think you were intending:

```
DayOfWeek day = (DayOfWeek)Enum.Parse(typeof(DayOfWeek), activity.Parameters[0].Name);
```

You should be storing the `activity` at each iterations parameter name. This parses it to the enum type.

Also, you should be storing the body of the expression for the activity name:

```
ActivityName = activity.Body.ToString()
```

Allowing this:

```
activityRecorder.WithActivities(Monday => "Something", Tuesday => "Something");
```

This is awfully hacky.. so I would definitely re-think what it is you're trying to do. If you're trying to create an expression builder (as the article is), then you should just build expressions and pass them straight down to NHibernate.

If you're not doing that.. then you should really look into walking the expressions properly and deciding what you want to do with them.

Without any more context as to what you are hoping to eventually use this for.. that's the best I can do (someone else probably has better ideas.. and if thats the case I will happily remove my answer).

Comment: +1. Nice advice. Thanks. I was just trying to do that **fancy-stuff**, but like you say, its hacky. I ll just stick to the traditional way. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

The code in that blog post doesn't even compile, and I wouldn't use it anyhow. Expression trees incur a large overhead, and using object initializers for this purpose is more readable anyway.

**Why it doesn't work**

When you write a lambda, even as an expression, the left side is the parameters of the lambda - their types and names, not their values. So `Monday` and `Tuesday` in your code are just literals of parameter names. The compiler won't verify they are valid enum members.

**Shorter syntax option**

Use constructor parameters for the `Activity` class:

```
recorder.AddActivities(new Activity("DeepSeaDiving", DayOfWeek.Monday),
                       new Activity("Lawn Mowing", DayOfWeek.Tuesday));
```

You can also use a collection initializer for your `WeeklyActivityRecorder` class:

```
class WeeklyActivityRecorder : IEnumerable
{
   public void Add(string name, DayOfWeek day) { ... }

   IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator() { return Activities.GetEnumerator(); }
}

var recorder = new WeeklyActivityRecorder {
    { "DeepSeaDiving", DayOfWeek.Monday },
    { "Lawn Mowing", DayOfWeek.Tuesday} };
```

Comment: I think that dismissing `Expression` purely on based on performance is premature optimization.

Comment: But I agree that collection initializer is the right solution here. For it to work, you also have to implement `IEnumerable`. Also, I think the parameters of `Add()` should be the other way around (first `day`, then `name`).

Comment: @EliArbel: Thanks for the `collection-initializer` and the explanation.

Answer (score 1):

The code you'd provided is wrong on many levels.

First, there is no direct implicit casting from ParameterExpression to DayOfWeek enum in this line:

```
DayOfWeek day = expression.Parameters[0];
```

And that's why you get the mentioned compiler error.

Second, the whole idea of the *WithActivities* extension method is wrong. You cannot extract the runtime information from the parameters of expression. And the exact value you pass is **runtime** info.

Third, you cannot use the *Monday* or the *Tuesday* names as shown, until they are members of the caller class. Otherwise they are just names of the parameter and you don't have any intellisense support for them.

So the whole point of using expression trees for the matter is beyond my understanding. A close thing, not involving expression trees but providing a fluent interface would look like:

```
public static WeeklyActivityRecorder WithActivity(this WeeklyActivityRecorder recorder, DayOfWeek day, string activity)
{
    recorder.AddActivity(new Activity {ActivityName = activity, DayOfWeek = day});

    return recorder;
}
```

And the usage:

```
new WeeklyActivityRecorder()
    .WithActivity(DayOfWeek.Monday, "Lawn Moving")
    .WithActivity(DayOfWeek.Tuesday, "Cooking");
```

Comment: +1. Thanks. BTW, Your extension method seems good & shorter! f**k, the article is a complete waste of time.